# Javascript prompt() - cancel button to terminate the function

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm calling a Javascript `window.prompt()` and prompting the user to submit a variable which I compare to another variable (a very basic password protection). The function works great, however, if you click `"cancel"` on the `prompt()` window, the function does not simply terminate, but rather compares the variable to an empty string, (which the user opted not to submit by pressing "cancel" instead) resulting in the function continuing to the `else{ }` portion.

My question is, how do I terminate the function upon pressing cancel? I just need to know how to target the cancel button.

Usually I would just call a `.stop()` on the `click()` of a button, but I don't know how to target the prompt-window's cancel button.

Comment: use event.target..it will give you target element reference.

Comment: `prompt` returns `null` when the cancel button is pressed.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

[`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt) returns a string if the user presses `OK` (`''` being with no value submitted). If the user pressed `Cancel`, `null` is returned. All you need to do is check whether the value is `null`:

```
function doSomething() {
    var input;
    input = prompt('Do something?');
    if (input === null) {
        return; //break out of the function early
    }
    switch (input) {
    case 'fun':
        doFun();
        break;
    case 'boring':
        beBoring();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton for your help! Your explanation made it seem so obvious it was like a slap across the face! Haha. Thanks again. :)

Comment: If this answered your question, be sure to select the checkmark next to it to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Ok - I'm a noobie to this site, so I didn't know.

Comment: @JustinWard, Then I recommend reviewing the [faq] if you haven't already. [Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) is also useful.

Answer (score 8):

You should explicitly check for `null` as the return value (using triple-equals) and `return` when this is the result.

```
var result = prompt("OK?");
if (result === null) {
    return;
}
```

This allows you to distinguish from the empty string, which is what's returned when the user clicks `OK` but enters no content.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton for your help! Exactly what I was looking for. Pretty damn simple, really. I completely forgot about returns of 'null'.

Answer (score 5):

One substantial problem with handling the result of 'prompt' is that Safari (at least version 9.1.2) returns "" instead of null when "Cancel" is clicked. This means that: if(result==null) return;    does not work, and you cannot distinguish between entry of a null string, and cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
message = prompt("Enter text");
if(message == "null" || message == null || message == "" );
```

This worked for me.

Comment: What if the user really wanted to provide the string "null"?

Comment: remove the first one. There is no reason for the user to input the string "null"

Answer (score 2):

Can you just check for

```
if (prompt_responce == null)
```

to tell if it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks cancel, this code should check for it:

```
$message = prompt("Please enter xxx");
if($message){
  //compare logic
}else{
  // warn or simply return nothing
  return;
}
```

Comment: This answer is better for its simplicity, it checks both necessary conditions (null and empty) in just one condition.