# JavaScript: Functions - How to activate cancel button

Tags: javascript, function, button

I'm calling a Javascript window.prompt() and prompting the user to submit an integer number one at a time. if user click "cancel" on the prompt() window, the function should terminate the session but I could not find the function to solve this problem.

My question is, how do I terminate the function upon pressing cancel?

This is my program:

```
function isOdd(n) 
{
    return n % 2 == 1; // Checking if the number is odd or not
}


    // sentinel-controlled loop here
    while (true) {
        var n = Number(prompt("Enter an integer (click Cancel to terminate)", "0"));

        if(n === -1) {
            break;
            }
    if(isOdd(n)) {
        alert(n + " is odd.");
        }   
    else {
        alert(n + " is even.");
        }
    }

    // trying to find a solution for cancel button
    //document.getElementById("Button ID").click()

    //function cancel () {
        //var cancelButton = document.getElementById( "cancel");
        //}


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action = "#">
        <input id = "cancel" type = "button" value = "cancel">
    </form>

    <h1>Odd/Even Output</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I searched on Google for "js prompt cancel", and it found this earlier StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12864582/812973).

Answer (score 2):

"If the user clicks the Cancel button, this function returns null."

```
var promptResult = prompt(...)

if(!promptResult) {
   break;
}
// parse and rest of the function
```

Answer (score 1):

[Window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns `null` if the cancel button is clicked. You need to add in a case to handle that.

```
var result = prompt("Enter an integer (click Cancel to terminate)", "0");
if(result === null) {
    return;
}
var n = Number(result);
```